# rtl8812bu driver: can only access non encryped ssid's

Tags: drivers, devices, realtek, wlan

I installed rtl88x2BU on a new installation of MINT 19.3 (kernel 5.3.0.40), source: github [cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2BU_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_27678.20180430_COEX20180427-5959), using the README.md instuctions for DKMS installation.

I can only connect to non-encrypted ssid's. When using an encrypted ssid it fails to establish the link.

Since I had installed the module before while plugged-in the usb device I cleared the installation using

sudo rmod 88x2bu

and repeated the installation successfully but with the problem that I cannot connect to a WPA / WPA2 personal protected ssid.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome, a bug already [reported here](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu/issues/4). Something to try:Stop the networkmanager service then try to connect through `wpa_supplicant` or `wpa_cli`.